# Razor HtmlHelpers with sub-sections?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

Is there a way to build the custom Html Helpers and put them into sub-sections? I.e:

```
@Html.Buttons.Gray
@Html.Buttons.Blue
@Html.Tables.2Columns
@Html.Tables.3Columns
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers are simply extension methods. So you could create helpers that return object that allow you to chain method calls, e.g. `@Html.Button("Text").Grey()`.

```
public ButtonHelper
{
   public string Text {get; set;}
   public MvcHtmlString Grey()
   {
      return MvcHtmlString.Create("<button class='grey'>"+ Text +"</button>");
   }
}

public static class Buttons
{
   public static ButtonHelper Button(this HtmlHelper, string text)
   {
      return new ButtonHelper{Text = text};
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it like that.  Create an enum and then use that to reference colors, like so:

```
public enum ButtonColor
{
    Blue = 0x1B1BE0,
    Gray = 0xBEBECC
};

public static class Extensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string Value, ButtonColor buttonColor)
    {
        string renderButton = 
            string.Format(
                @"<input type=""button"" value=""{0}"" style=""background-color: {1}"" />", 
                Value, 
                buttonColor.ToString()
            );

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(renderButton);
    }
}
```

You could do the same type of thing for the table, but this should give you the general idea.  It's a normal helper extension method, but takes an enum val as the parameter to give you the desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid Buttons() being a function, see http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx for how to accomplish something like this by creating a custom HtmlHelper: `@MyAppHtml.Buttons.Gray`

You might be able to instead override HtmlHelper instead if you strictly want `@Html.Buttons.Gray`