# How to create a custom class similar to HtmlHelper and initialize with ViewContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, viewcontext

Our project uses a lot of custom HtmlHelper extension methods to be referenced in views like:

```
@Html.MyHelperMethod()
```

However, I'd like to keep them separated out from the system ones and be able to do something like either of the following:

```
@Html.MyApp.MyHelperMethod()
@MyAppHtml.MyHelperMethod()
```

By following [Razor HtmlHelpers with sub-sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298990/razor-htmlhelpers-with-sub-sections) I was able to implement something like

```
@Html.MyApp().MyHelperMethod()
```

This just doesn't look as pretty with MyApp() as a function haha. So I set out to make my own class. I want it to be able to access the ViewContext just like HtmlHelper does:

```
public class MyHtmlHelper
{
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; private set; }

    public MyHtmlHelper(ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        this.ViewContext = viewContext;
    }

    public MvcHtmlString MyHelperMethod()
    {
        //... Do something that accesses this.ViewContext
    }
}
```

However, I have no idea what to inherit and override (ViewPage?), where to put a MyHtmlHelper property or where to initialize. The other alternative idea I can come up with is create a BaseModel object all models inherit from and add a MyHtmlHelper property in it in order to do

```
@Model.MyAppHtml.MyHelperMethod()
```

This would require every controller method pass the context to the model object (in order to reference ViewContext), but this seems like a tedious trade-off. Any other ideas on how to "subsection" the helper methods not using functions?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to answers here, I found a detailed example in creating a custom HtmlHelper class like this: [Changing Base Type Of A Razor View](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class that inherits [`WebViewPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and adds your custom property, then change all of your views to inherit that class.

You can change the default base class in Web.config.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I found a detailed guide on doing exactly this and a custom HtmlHelper: [Changing Base Type Of A Razor View](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have the skeleton how you can proceed as follows

```
public MtWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage
{
  public HtmlHelper<TModel> MyHtml {get;set;}
}
```